# Is the formula right about the number of subgroups of group.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the following formula right?

"Let G be a group of order m(>4) and m is a multiple of 4.And let $n_{2}$ be the number of Sylow 2-subgroups of G.

Then the number of subgroups of order 4 is $n_{2}\times 3$."

Any help please.

Comment: What about $G=\mathbb{Z}_4$? I don't see where that formula might come from without further assumptions on $G$.

Comment: sorry, I edited.

Comment: What about $G=\mathbb{Z}_8$? Still a unique subgroup of order $4$.
Where does this question come from?

Comment: what about nonabelian group?

Comment: I have a counterexample, but I want you to try by yourself. It would really help if you gave the context of the problem.